# What is the most minimal setup I can use to run VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, dell-dimension

I have an older Dell C521 computer with a decent processor and 8GB of memory. I no longer use the machine but would like to have it available for testing operating systems using VirtualBox.

When testing I want as much of the system resources available for the "guest" operating system as possible.

What base operating system should I use to get the most bang for my buck out of Virtualbox?

I was thinking Ubuntu, but it would be nice if there was something even more minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While a standard Ubuntu desktop install uses around 400-700MB you could try a Ubuntu Server install. The overheads are drastically reduced as there is no GUI. I do not have any expereince with other linux types so cannot say in regards to their effectiveness.

Do you have to use VirtualBox? Consider using a bare-metal virtulisation package such as ESXi (VirtualBox, on the other hand, needs a OS installed on it already).

Answer (score 1):

Default Ububtu setup (i.e. with Unity DE) could barely be considered lightweight. If you stick to Ubuntu, you can install [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server), and, if necessary, some lightweight desktop environment (LXDE, for example). The OS itself does not consume a lot of resources, so it does not matter that much.

However, if the machine will be used for virtualization only, you could use bare-metal vistualization solutions, such as [ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/overview.html), which are essentially minimal Linux setup + virtualization solution.

Comment: Would Ubuntu be consider lightweight when compared to Windows? Thanks for the note about ESXi :)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Server should do it, and so will any Linux distro. You do not need to run a GUI: the VMs can be managed with something like [phpvirtualbox](https://phpvirtualbox.github.io/).

But for a machine that will only be used for virtualization, [ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/overview.html) should be better. However, ESXi **requires hardware virtualization support**. Looking at [Dell's datasheet for the C521](https://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/dimc521/en/SM_EN/specs.htm), it's unclear whether the CPUs used in this model have this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You could install Ubuntu and still go for a lightweight GUI by replacing unity. In case you don't opt for Ubuntu there are flavors such as lubuntu which can run even on as low as 256 mb of ram.